# Round datetime to the beginning of the current hour

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I would like to round a datetime (should also return a datetime) to the beginning of the hour it's on, so for example:

```
2018-09-22 11:31:42.411 -> 2018-09-22 11:00:00.000
2018-09-22 11:08:02.456 -> 2018-09-22 11:00:00.000
2018-09-22 11:52:08.005 -> 2018-09-22 11:00:00.000
```

Can someone help with this please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the datatype is `DATETIME` or `DATETIME2` you can use this common trick:

```
SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, yourdate), 0)
```

`DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, yourdate)` will give you the number of hours (and nothing else) between the zeroth date and yourdate. When you add those hours back to the zeroth date you get yourdate "floored" to the hour.

Answer (score 3):

Another method is the `DATEADD`, `DATEDIFF`:

```
SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, '20000101',YourColumn),'20000101') AS RoundedValue
FROM YourTable;
```

Comment: Can you explain what this is doing?

Comment: @Azhari It works out the difference in hours between `'200-01-01'` and your column, and then adds that many hours to `'2000-01-01'`.

Comment: I need it to round to the beginning of the current hour

Comment: @Azhari and that's what it does.

Comment: And worth pointing out - `20000101` is an *arbitrary* date. Doesn't matter (mostly) what value you use so long as you use the same value twice. (You are missing a `0` though)

Comment: Correct, a lot of people use `0` instead; I used `'2000-01-01'` as it was more likely to be clearer to the OP. *(`0` in `datetime` represents `'1900-01-01'`).*

Comment: Small comment, there is a typo in the first date, one 0 missing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DATETIMEFROMPARTS()` Function.

```
select DATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@date),MONTH(@date),DAY(@date),DATEPART(HOUR,@date),00,00,00)
```

Here @date is replaced with YourColumn or any variable.

Answer (score 0):

This converts the value to a string, takes the left 14 chars and add the 00:00:00 values

```
select  left(convert(varchar , datecol, 121),14) + '00:00:00'  as mydatecol from table
```